# Excel Conditional Format duplicate rows with mismatched record

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have employee records where an employee can have more than one row based on his rate, I want to format the rows where the employee Id is not unique to the employee
if the id is duplicated but his last name and first name are not the same as the duplicate ID to highlight the mismatched records. picture example Shows a mismatched rows in row 2 and row 8 ; records in row 5 and 6. Thanks for your help in advance.[Image of excel data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzvnT.jpg)

Comment: I tried this formula is Conditional formatting: =COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,A1,$B$1:$B$9,B1,$C$1:$C$9,C1)+COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,A1)=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the times a unique ID excists against the times the ID exists along with first and last name with the following:

- Select range `A2:D10`
- Insert new conditional formatting rule > Formula:

  ```
  =COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10,$A2)<>COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,$A2,$B$2:$B$10,$B2,$C$2:$C$10,$C2)
  ```
- Apply a format and confirm

[image]

Comment: It's working properly ☺

Comment: JvdV: Thank you so much for your answer